# Mod_rewrite delete parameter in 301 Redirect

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

How would I go about rewriting:

```
http://www.example.com/?aff=number
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com
```

I want to remove all instances on `aff=x` regardless of how many other parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to remove all instances on `aff=x` regardless of how many other parameters in the URL.

Assuming you want to *keep* any other URL parameters (in any order) and simply remove the `aff=number` parameter, then you can do something like the following using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)aff=\d+(?:&(.*)|)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [R=302,L]
```

This will need to go *before* the existing WordPress directives.

This assumes that if the `aff` parameter is present it will have a value of only digits and at least 1 digit.

The `$1` is a backreference to the captured `RewriteRule` *pattern*. So, this will handle any URL-path, not just the document root, as in your example.

`%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the captured groups in the previous *CondPattern*. `%1` is *before* the parameter to be removed and `%2` is after. Both are optional.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) only after you have confirmed this is working OK (if this is intended to be permanent).

---

#### **UPDATE#1:** Query string contains %-encoded characters

If any of the other URL parameters (that you want to keep) contain URL-encoded (%-encoded) values then you will need to add the `NE` (`noescape`) flag to the `RewriteRule` directive to prevent these characters from being doubly encoded in the *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded by Apache. Normally, mod_rewrite URL-encodes the *substitution* before sending the response back to the client. But this will doubly encode any already-encoded characters that we have captured from the query string. The `NE` flag prevents this from happening.

---

#### **UPDATE#2:** URL parameter value to be removed could be *anything*

The question specifically dealt with removing a URL parameter called `aff` that contained a "number". Generally, you should be as specific as possible when dealing with regex, however, if the URL parameter to be removed can contain *anything* then modify the *CondPattern* to be something like one of the following

- `^(.*&|)aff=.*?(?:&(.*)|)$` - a non-greedy match of 0 or more characters.
- `^(.*&|)aff=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$` - matches anything except `&` (URL parameter delimiter) 0 or more times.

The important point in both of these regex is that the *value* being matched is not *captured*, ie. must not be surrounded in plain parentheses.

In summary:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)aff=[^&]*(?:&(.*)|)$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1?%1%2 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Comment: This solution doesn’t work when a parameter contains a non-ASCII character: How do I use this snippet, but keep a parameter such as `x=é`, which with the code above, redirects to https://example.com/?x=%25C3%25A9 instead of https://example.com/?x=%C3%A9

Comment: @Lucas You'll need to add the `NE` flag to the `RewriteRule` directive. I've updated my answer.

Comment: The `NE` does indeed protect the characters from being doubly escaped, but now the `x=é` (or `aff=é`) parameter is not being removed. If it is the final parameter, I am able to force it to work by using the following as my `RewriteCond`, but I understand that I’m catching to much with the first `(.*)` here:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)aff=(.*)+(?:&(.*)|)$`

Comment: "but now the `x=é` (or `aff=é`) parameter is not being **removed**" - The question specifically dealt with number values, so that is correct, it shouldn't be removed. You also stated in your first comment, "**keep** a parameter such as `x=é`" - you can't "remove" and "keep" the same parameter. However, if the URL param to be removed can itself contain _anything_ then you will need to modify the regex. The problem with your suggestion is that it is indeed matching too much (greedy), but you are also _capturing_ the pattern so the backreference will be incorrect. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Lucas How did you get on with the last update?

Comment: it works exactly like you explained — thanks so much!